# How to display json data from js file in html page inside div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Here,I am getting data from db in JSON format into my .js file and I am getting in div also .But I am not getting the  div in my HTML page.Please can anyone tell me how to show in my HTML page.Below is my code:

My json array:

```
[{"chat_question_id":"1",
 "chat_question_title":"What is PHP?"},
 {"chat_question_id":"17",
 "chat_question_title":"what is php?",}
```

Below is my js code:

```
    function ChatQuestionsInfo(bRowId)
    {
    var actionType = "";
    var hdnFlagForSearchQue = $("#hdnFlagForSearchQue").val();
    if(hdnFlagForSearchQue=="insert"){
        actionType = "ChatQuestionsInfo";
    } else {
        actionType = "searchQuestiontitle";
    }
    if($.trim($("#questionname").val())==""){
        $("#questionname").focus();
        alert("Enter Question Name");
        return false;
    }
    if($.trim($("#technologytags").val())==""){
        $("#technologytags").focus();
        return false;
    }
    $.post(rootUrl+"includes/ajax/ajax_chat.php", {action: actionType,bRowId:bRowId,bQuestionName: $.trim($("#questionname").val()),bTechnologyTags: $.trim($("#technologytags").val())},
    function(data){
       var htmlText = '';
  for ( var key in data ) {
            htmlText += '<div class="tab-content">';
            htmlText += '<div id="newquestions"> : ' + data[key].chat_question_title + '</div>';
            htmlText += '</div>';
        }
        $('.chat_body_form').append(htmlText);
    }, "json");
    return false;
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="newquestions"></div>
```

Comment: alert is working ???

Comment: no, it's not working

Comment: print your object in console and show me 
like `console.log(chat) ;` that will print in console window

Comment: what is the value of row.date?show us the data of row or chat variable.

Comment: I changed my code I am getting in alert like this    I am getting in alert like this:

    <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="newquestions"> : What is PHP?</div>
    </div>

Comment: But is should display in html

Comment: but i just want to see that array then i can suggest you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make 2 changes, 1 is in ajax_chat.php file. and second in your javascript.

1. Every JSON output need to have in pure JSON output, so javascript (or jquery) can easily read it. so on output of ajax_chat.php file, you have to set a header to give proper output content type.

**for example**

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode('your varialbe array');
```

2. In jquery it is better to use $.each then for loop, and also you can append the data directly in the loop.

**for example**

```
function(data){
$.each(data,function(i){
    $('.chat_body_form').append('<div class="tab-content"><div id="newquestions"> : '+ $(this).chat_question_title + '</div></div>';
 });    
}
```

I think these changes will work and also will be very simple and clean code to understand or change,

Thanks...